# What should I do when (CUDA 7.5's) nvcc/cudafe++ crashes with a segfault?

Tags: c++, compilation, cuda, segmentation-fault

I was compiling some teplated CUDA code today, when suddenly, I get:

```
nvcc foo.cu -dc -o foo.o -m64 --std c++11 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=compute_30  -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -I/path/to/includes 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is with CUDA 7.5 and GCC 4.9.3 on Debian Stretch. Boost and CUB are not actually used by the code triggering the segfault.

running gdb, I get:

```
...
Reading symbols from /usr/local/cuda/bin/cudafe++...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New LWP 26725]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `cudafe++ --allow_managed --m64 --gnu_version=40903 --c++11 --parse_templates --'.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000458b48 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000458b48 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000447989 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000449a77 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000444d6b in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000004467f1 in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000446bd5 in ?? ()
#6  0x00000000004536e7 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000000446c95 in ?? ()
#8  0x00000000004536e7 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000446c95 in ?? ()
#10 0x0000000000448403 in ?? ()
#11 0x000000000040b042 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007f3637c17610 in __libc_start_main (main=0x40af50, argc=14, argv=0x7ffd24a32058, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffd24a32048) at libc-start.c:291
#13 0x0000000000401769 in ?? ()
#14 0x00007ffd24a32048 in ?? ()
#15 0x000000000000001c in ?? ()
#16 0x000000000000000e in ?? ()
#17 0x00007ffd24a33e7b in ?? ()
#18 0x00007ffd24a33e84 in ?? ()
#19 0x00007ffd24a33e94 in ?? ()
#20 0x00007ffd24a33e9a in ?? ()
#21 0x00007ffd24a33eae in ?? ()
#22 0x00007ffd24a33eb6 in ?? ()
#23 0x00007ffd24a33ec8 in ?? ()
#24 0x00007ffd24a33ed3 in ?? ()
#25 0x00007ffd24a33ee5 in ?? ()
#26 0x00007ffd24a33f16 in ?? ()
#27 0x00007ffd24a33f27 in ?? ()
#28 0x00007ffd24a33f56 in ?? ()
#29 0x00007ffd24a33f6c in ?? ()
#30 0x00007ffd24a33f9b in ?? ()
#31 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

So that's not very useful. What can I try doing to avoid this segfault? Or to figure out why it happens?

**Edit:** I just noticed [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13829791/1593077) - but it doesn't have an answer yet.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: It's not _my_ code which segfaults, it's nvcc (or cudafe++)... I'll deal with my bugs in due time... Oh, I guess I had a quoted line missing. Fixed now.

Comment: File a bug report with NVIDIA. Maybe try simplifying the code you are trying to compile to isolate what might be the code which is causing the goldfish to choke

Comment: I had the same issue once. does nvcc 7.0 reproduce? For me it "solved" the issue... reporting a bug to nvidia is probably a good thing if you can do it

Comment: @RegisPortalez: Will try CUDA 7.0 and see.

Comment: @talonmies: In the process of doing that, I'm noticing the segfault happens even if I comment out _all_ of my actually-instantiated code and only leave templates with no new implementation of anything.

Comment: @einpoklum: That isn't too suprising. It is traditionally complex or subtly broken  template declarations which cause the C++ front end to either crash or fail to compile code which it should otherwise parse correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the reason for the crash is failure to prevent an inappropriate use of the `using` keyword. Here's a non-MCVE (which I might make into an MCVE later):

```
enum class foo : bool { foolish = false, snafu = true };

template <typename T> class bar {
public:
    using foo::foolish;
    using foo::snafu;
}
```

This is incorrect C++, and should make the compiler give out an error, but for some reason, and possibly due to combination with more code not in this snippet, that didn't happen. Instead, `cudafe++` is tricked into accepting that, gets confused and crashes.

As @talonmies suggested, will try to make a proper bug report to nVIDIA. ...

**Edit:** It's proving difficult to reproduce now :-(